# calculating a probability from a T-table

Tags: statistics

[image]

This problem comes from Probability and Statistics for Engineers by Scheaffer, Mulekar, McClave

Can someone please lead me in the right direction here? My understanding is that I cannot use a Z-score here because I am not being given the population standard deviation. Thus I have

$t = ((x̅ - u)$ $\sqrt{n}$)) / $s$

$u = 200, n = 15, df = 14, s = 10$

Of course, one confusing part of the question is that it states there are 15 resistors but the standard deviation is of "12" measurements. I'm just assuming this should be "15" measurements, thus s = 10

a) plugging in the values of $x̅ = 199$ and $x̅ = 202$ I get $-0.3873$ and $0.7746$

$P(-0.3873 \leq t \leq 0.7746)$ with $df = 14$ using a calculator I get $0.422$

The book has an answer key for odd numbers in the back, and the only thing they have is 0.3224 which makes even less sense because that's one answer for a two-part question.

b) 5,100 ohms among 15 resistors is an average of $340$.

Plugging this into $t = ((x̅ - u)$ $\sqrt{n}$)) / $s$ I get that $t = 54.22$ which is a ridiculous number because to my understanding, this is supposed to represent a deviation from the mean. Yet it doesn't seem unreasonable, because if the expected value is 200, 15 resistors at random should be *about* 3000 ohms. The likelihood of them adding up to a number greater than 5,100 seems like it should be virtually impossible (and that is reflected in the numbers)

Even if I did use Z-Scores, it wouldn't give me a more rational answer. Can someone please give me a sanity check here? Am I doing something extraordinarily wrong or is this question just complete nonsense? These aren't the first errors I've found in this book. They're not even the 10th errors I've found in this book. The authors of this book should be embarrassed for publishing this text, and my university should be equally embarassed for teaching from it. Excuse my rant, It's more frustrating than I can put into words trying to learn content that I personally find challenging compounded with dozens of careless mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poorly worded question and I don't blame you for being confused.  And the claimed answer is wrong.

The intent of the question is that the standard deviation of the resistance is estimated as $\hat \sigma = 10$, based on $12$ measurements, and that this estimate is assumed to represent the true standard deviation $\sigma$.  Therefore, no $t$-distribution is used for this question at all.  Everything is calculated using a normal distribution.  Don't ask me how I know; it's just experience from reading too many badly written statistics textbook questions.

So what you're trying to do--using a $t$-distribution to model the sample mean--won't work.  To understand why, let's suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ represents an iid sample of resistances.  With $n = 15$ such observations, the sample mean is $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$  You are asked to calculate the probability $$\Pr[199 \le \bar X \le 202]$$ under the assumption that $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 200, \sigma = \sigma_x),$$ which is equivalent to $$\bar X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 200, \sigma_{\bar x} = \sigma_x/\sqrt{15}).$$  Note here that I have left $\sigma_x$ unknown.  Now, you could standardize: $$\Pr[199 \le \bar X \le 202] = \Pr\left[\frac{199 - 200}{\sigma_{\bar x}} \le \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma_{\bar x}} \le \frac{202 - 200}{\sigma_{\bar x}}\right],$$ and the quantity in the center of the inequality is standard normal, *but you don't know* $\sigma_{\bar x}$ unless you use the estimate $\sigma_x = \hat \sigma = 10.$  However, if you studentize, you are even worse off:  $$\Pr[199 \le \bar X \le 202] = \Pr\left[\frac{199 - 200}{s/\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\bar X - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{202 - 200}{s/\sqrt{n}}\right]$$ where $s$ is the sample standard deviation $$s = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 }$$ estimated from the same sample, and now the quantity in the center is student $t$ with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom.  But even if you knew the value of $s$ (which you don't because it is a random variable), you cannot use it to solve for $\bar X$ because you don't know the individual values of the $X_i$.  This approach is impossible.  So the only feasible interpretation here is to use the normal model and assume that $\sigma_x = \hat \sigma$.  Under this assumption, the answer should be $0.43144330780783071032\ldots$.

In any case, for the second part of the question, the answer is effectively $1$, no matter what model you use.  This is because the mean of the total of $15$ resistors is going to be $200(15) = 3000$ ohms, well below $5100$ ohms--in fact, it is over $54$ standard deviations above the mean.  The resulting probability is less than $1$ by about $2 \times 10^{-641}$, and even if you assume a standard deviation that is $10$ times larger, the probability is still around $0.99999997$.  Such questions are not interesting to ask.

---

I would also like to add in closing that sometimes we learn more from badly written textbooks than we do from a good one, because it keeps us vigilant.  If you feel like you can't trust everything in the book to be accurate, you're more likely to work harder to check every claim in it.  In a perverse way, this can lead to a better understanding of the material, especially if you have access to a better text where you can compare the two.  When working on poorly written questions such as these, your goal shouldn't be to replicate the answers that are provided.  Sometimes, it won't even be possible to give any meaningful answer to a bad question.  Instead, the goal should be to formulate a complete response to the question by addressing the following:

1. In what ways is the question deficient/defective, and why?
2. How would you rewrite or correct the question so that it can be answered?
3. How would you write up a complete, step-by-step solution to such a revised question?

In essence, this is the approach I have taken above.

Comment: Thank you. Adding to the confusion is the fact that this problem was written as an exercise directly following the explanation about t-probabilities. However, I've since learned that the book was co-authored by my university's mathematics Chair, which answers some questions.